# New window from Gnome search box

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3

On the results from the search box in Gnome 3, you can right click on an icon and choose *New Window*:

[image: Gnome 3 Search Box]

Otherwise, if a window already exists, it will focus on that window instead of opening a new one.

How can I make an application, e.g. Terminal or Firefox, open a new window by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the default, I found out that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will open a new window for the first item in the search results, rather than focusing on an existing window.